# Filter table to exclude rows if they contain a value in a column of a second table

Tags: r

I have got one main table with over ###,000 rows (the first 7 rows are depicted below). These correspond to locations in the genome along with one (or two identifiers) given to them by Affymetrix (and dbSNP).

```
Affy SNP ID dbSNP RS ID Chromosome  Chromosome Start
Affx-26018273   rs10056215  5   163542505
```

I then have another table with only 46 rows. I need to remove the rows from the main table if they have both the Chromosome and Chromosome Start values found in one of the 46 rows in the second table. Here is the second table; it does not have the Affymetrix/dbSNP identifiers.

```
1   5641055
```

How can I filter out these records?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `anti_join` function from the `dplyr` package, or that package's `filter` function.

Say your data.frame was the built-in `mtcars` and you wanted to filter out cars with cylinder values from the following data.frame, i.e., with 4 or 6 cylinders:

```
dontuse <- data.frame(cyl = c(4,6), blah = c(1,2))
```

You could run:

```
anti_join(mtcars, dontuse)
```

or

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(! cyl %in% dontuse$cyl)
```

Both of these return rows where `cyl` is not 4 or 6.

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
2  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
3  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
4  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
5  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
6  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
7  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
8  14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
9  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
10 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
11 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
12 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
13 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
14 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `R`, you can remove all the rows from `Tab1` that have in the last column a number that appears in the second column of the 46-row table `Tab2`with

```
 Tab1 <- Tab1[-which(Tab1[,ncol(Tab1)] %in% Tab2[,2]),]
```

Hope this helps.